# Java - Does javax.websocket.Session and javax.servlet.http.HttpSession use the same JSESSIONID?

Tags: java, http, session, websocket, jsessionid

I would like to know if [getId() method from javax.websocket.Session](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/websocket/Session.html#getId--) and [getId() method from javax.servlet.http.HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getId--) always share the same JSESSIONID.

NB: I know that those two methods are **implementation dependent**, and I didn't find a link between those two session id on the internet/documentation.

Goal: A client connects to my website (a JSESSIONID is created) and is authentified by a login/password (client object is linked to the JSESSIONID), then he uses website's chat ... will he be recognized by his session id from the websocket ?

=> If the anwser is "no, it's not always the same", could you propose an alternative solution ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The ids of a websocket Session and a `HttpSession` are not related.

A simple reason is that a client which is associated with a server side `HttpSession` can have multiple websocket sessions which all need an own unique id.